# Test Proximity Sensor on android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, ddms, proximity

I wrote a simple activity which listens to the proximity sensor (http://thecodeartist.blogspot.co.il/2011/01/proximity-sensor-on-android-gingerbread.html), and I'm trying to test it on my emulator. That app works on a real device (checked on Nexus 4).

I've been reading somewhere that I should modify some values inside "Location Controls" in the DDMS for invoking that alert (for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048559/can-i-test-proximity-alert-in-the-emulator), but I still don't get it - how does the location is related to the proximity sensor which should only alert "Far" or "Near"?

I'd really appreciate your help,
Thanks.

this is my code (generic and simple):

```
package com.example.proximitysensor;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;

    private Sensor mProximitySensor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mProximitySensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
    }

    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mProximitySensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (event.values[0] == 0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "near", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "far", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```